# Pika - How to handle the NoneTypes exception when start consume

Tags: rabbitmq, python-pika

I'm trying to validation `channel.consume` when get message from RabbitMQ server using Pika 0.11.2

When call `get_mq` and I detected that: the exception occurd when empty message in queue. So, how can I valid the exception

Here my code:

```python
def send_mq(self, message, queue_name):
    try:
        if message and queue_name:
            message = json.dumps(message)
            self.connect(queue_name)
            self.channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key=queue_name, body=message)
            if self.mqConn:
                self.mqConn.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        sentry_log('send_mq_error', str(ex))

def get_mq(self, callback, queue_name, limit_message=0):
    if callback and queue_name:
        self.connect(queue_name)
        queue = self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)
        # Enabled delivery confirmations
        self.channel.confirm_delivery()
        if queue and queue.method.message_count > 0:
            # method_frame, header_frame, body = self.channel.basic_get(queue=queue_name)
            # self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
            # self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
            # self.channel.basic_consume(lambda ch, method, properties, body: callback(json.loads(body) if body else body), queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)
            # # # start consuming (blocks)
            # try:
            #     self.channel.start_consuming()
            # except KeyboardInterrupt:
            #     self.channel.stop_consuming()
            try:
                # Get ten messages and break out
                for method_frame, properties, body in self.channel.consume(queue=queue_name, inactivity_timeout=1):
                    if body:
                        # Acknowledge the message
                        self.channel.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)
                        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

                        # Escape out of the loop with limit messages
                        if limit_message > 0 and method_frame.delivery_tag == limit_message:
                            break

                        callback(json.loads(body))
                    else:
                        break
                self.channel.cancel()
            except Exception as ex:
                self.channel.cancel()
                if self.mqConn:
                    self.mqConn.close()
```

The error message:

> 'Nonetype' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

I am one of Pika's maintainers. The `consume` method can either return a 3-tuple **or** `None`, so you should handle it using the method [provided in this comment](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/760#issuecomment-228477849).

The issue has been resolved in this pull request and will ship in the next version of Pika: https://github.com/pika/pika/pull/901